# AlwaysON Failover Questions

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups

I actually have 2 Databases for one application under a SQLServer 2012 ALwaysON,
I want to add another Database for a different application... It is recommended to create a new AlwaysON AG Group?

I would like to know if is possible to have something like this:

AG Group 1
Server 1

- DBAPP1(PRIMARY)
- DBAPP2(PRIMARY)
- DBAPP3(SECONDARY)

AG Group 1
Server 2

- DBAPP1(SECONDARY)
- DBAPP2(SECONDARY)
- DBAPP3(PRIMARY)

Is this possible? Or just dumb?

Thanks!

Comment: ,Could you elaborate your both AG Data transfer( I mean to say that Synchronous or Asynchronous). How you want in both AG  Server & Backup Strategy?

Comment: The Data transfer is Synchronous as both servers are inside the same DataCenter. The backup strategy is driven by Tivoli Storage Manager, Full backup at the night and each 3 hours a log backup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so, when you failover you failover the whole AG. So in order to achieve this you'll need another AG. And probably another SQL Server License since you usually only license the active node in an AlwaysOn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was exactly what I was thinking...

By the way, I'm using Azure Virtual Machines with SQL Server Installed, so I guess that I won't have to License anything else :P